# How can I check whether Google keys are embeded/enabled in Chromium/Chrome or not?

Tags: google-chrome, google-api, chromium

I build Chromium with Google keys (Google API, Oauth Client ID, Oauth Client Secret).
I could embed above Google keys well in Chromium source before building.
But I wanna check the keys in Chromium binary after building.

If I type `chrome://version` in Chromium, can check flags which r adopted in Chromium browser. But I don't know how to check the keys.
Or I just wanna check whether the keys are enabled or not.

Is there a way to check whether Google API is embeded/enabled in Chromium/Chrome or not?

Answer (score 0):

Chromium will first try to read the value of these env. variables from the system before using embedded API keys, if they are present:

- GOOGLE_API_KEY
- GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID
- GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET

if they are not present then it will use embedded values instead.

There are a couple of ways to find out if a Chromium fork was compiled with Google API keys:

- If the API keys are absent, Chromium will show a bubble control on startup stating that API keys are missing. But as mentioned above, you can't find out if the API keys are embedded or read from env. variables using this method.
- Use Chrome sync feature to check if Google API keys are present or not. Just try to sync Google accounts with Chromium. If they keys are not present then it won't work. **FYI, this feature won't be available to Chromium browsers past March 15 because of policy changes led by Google.**
  Again, you can't use this method to find out if the API keys are embedded or not.
- **Use this method to find out if the API keys are embedded** you can find out by enabling logging when starting Chromium. You should go through the log file to find out if the API keys are being read from env. variable or are embedded. More info on how to enable logging: [Here](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging)